# Html to PDF , text inside <pre> not coming good in PDF

Tags: itext, itextpdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf with iText API(itextpdf.5.5.7.jar, xmlworker 5.5.7.jar), everything is good except the text inside the **pre** tag.

In html the text inside the **pre** is good but in PDF the formatting is totally gone and simply coming in normal lines without formatting. I checked the blogs but I did not find correct answer.

---

Please find the screen shots for HTML and PDF.

HTML screen:
[image: HTML screen]

PDF screen:
[image: PDF screen]

this is my code

```
String pdfFileName="C:\test.pdf";    
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream(pdfFileName));
writer.setInitialLeading(12.5f);
document.open();
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance()
        .getDefaultCssResolver(true);       
Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
        new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document,
                writer)));      
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);        
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);         
File input = new File(completeHtmlFilePath);
p.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input), "UTF-8"));        
document.close();           
return pdfFileNameWithPath;
```

Comment: For urgent questions, please contact your account manager at iText Group to get [Premium support](http://itextpdf.com/support). If you're not paying for your use of iText, then you should not use the word "urgent".

Comment: "the formatting is totally gone" - would you upload a screenshot of what is going wrong?